# multiple where clause value form different sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to run this query using 2 where clause with the value coming from a different sheet, which is giving an error

These work

```
=query(Expenses!A1:H, "select B,D,G,H where G=2023 and H="& VALUE(Data!D2))
=query(Expenses!A1:H, "select B,D,G,H where H="& VALUE(Data!D2))
```

This one does not and gives an error. What am I missing here

```
    =query(Expenses!A1:H, "select B,D,G,H where G="& VALUE(Data!D1)" and H="& VALUE(Data!D2))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

`=query(Expenses!A1:H, "select B,D,G,H where G="& VALUE(Data!D1)&" and H="& VALUE(Data!D2))`